# pypi not finding registered package

Tags: python, pypi

I have a package that I submitted to Pypi using the `python setup.py register` command: 
https://bitbucket.org/lskibinski/et3

You can see it here: 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi?name=et3&version=1.0&:action=display

However, for some mysterious reason, `pip install et3` doesn't work. The error I get is:

`$ pip install et3 -vvv --no-cache-dir
Collecting et3
  1 location(s) to search for versions of et3:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/et3/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/et3/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
  "GET /simple/et3/ HTTP/1.1" 200 111
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/et3/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement et3 (from versions: )
Cleaning up...
No matching distribution found for et3
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/luke/dev/python/lax/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/luke/dev/python/lax/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 299, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/home/luke/dev/python/lax/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 370, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/home/luke/dev/python/lax/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 522, in _prepare_file
    finder, self.upgrade, require_hashes)
  File "/home/luke/dev/python/lax/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 268, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/home/luke/dev/python/lax/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 491, in find_requirement
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for et3`

It seems like it can't find any versions to download. Do I need to specify something more than `download_url`? Are further manual steps required?

Answer (score 0):

ok, figured it out. `download_url` doesn't appear to do much at all. I had to do:

- `python setup.py register`
- `python setup.py sdist upload`

... and it now works. The documentation for all of this is terrible.